# Vector contains every value in range

Tags: r, range

I have a dataframe `testData` which is made up of many unique ids.  My objective is to identify whether or not the ids contain *all* of the numbers in the range of `month`, `yday`, and `week`

In other words, if `id` has all possible values in the range in `month`, then it should receive a `t`.  If `id` has all possible values in the range in `yday`, it should receive a `t`, and if `id` has all possible values in the range in `week`, it should receive a `t`.  Otherwise, it should receive an `f`

A sample of the data looks like this:

```
> testData
   id month yday week
1   1     1    1    1
2   3     1    2    1
3   4     1    3    1
4   2     1    4    1
5   3     3    5    1
6   4     1    6    1
7   2     1    7    1
8   3     1    8    2
9   1     1    9    2
10  5     1   10    2
11  3     2   11    1
12  4     1   12    1
13  5     1   13    1
14  1     1   14    1
```

The output should look something like this:

```
> output
  id month yday week
1  1     f    f    t
2  2     f    f    f
3  3     t    f    t
4  4     f    f    f
5  5     f    f    t
```

I know that one can check if a numbers are within a certain range with  `findInterval()`, but could someone suggest a method to check if numbers in a vector contain all integers within a range?

```
> dput(testData)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yday = 1:14, week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "month", 
"yday", "week"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testdata)
output<-testdata[,.(month=all(unique(testdata$month)%in%.SD$month),yday=all(unique(testdata$yday)%in%.SD$yday),Week=all(unique(testdata$week)%in%.SD$week)),by=(id)]

output
id month  yday  Week
1:  1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
2:  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
3:  3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
4:  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5:  5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Didn't see your answer when posting mine. Guess mine is more general and can adapt to a bigger number of columns. Feel free to edit to include my `Map` way of dealing with all the columns and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
testData_copy <-testData
testData %>%
group_by(id) %>%
summarise(month=n_distinct(month)== n_distinct(testData_copy$month),
          yday =n_distinct(yday) == n_distinct(testData_copy$yday),
          week =n_distinct(week) == n_distinct(testData_copy$week)
)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id month  yday  week
  <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
2     2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
3     3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
4     4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5     5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```