# Find all numbers in range with local min and global max

Tags: r, range, data.table, dplyr

I have a dataframe `testData` which is made up of many unique ids.  My objective is to identify whether or not the ids contain *all* of the possible integers in the range of `month`, `yday`, and `week`   **where the min is the first value per id and max is the max value in the entire range of the column**

Please note this is different from the [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427806/vector-contains-every-value-in-range/43427965#43427965)

In other words, if `id` has all possible values in the range in `month`, then it should receive a `t`.  For example,  under `month` where `id` = 1, the min value is 2 and the max value for the whole column is 5, therefore 1 should receive a true because there is a value 2, 3, 4, and 5.  Where `id` = 2, however, there are only values 1, 2, 4, and 5, so the 3 was skipped and therefore 2 should receive an `f`.

So far, I have a formula that takes all the values in the entire range of the column (but *NOT* the min value per `id`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testData)
output<-testData[,.(month=all(unique(testData$month)%in%.SD$month),yday=all(unique(testData$yday)%in%.SD$yday),week=all(unique(testData$week)%in%.SD$week)),by=(id)]
```

Any idea how I could integrate `min` where `min` is the minimum value per `id` and `max` is the maximum value in the range?

```
> testData
   id month yday week
1   1     2    1    1
2   3     1    2    1
3   4     1    3    1
4   2     1    4    1
5   3     3    5    2
6   4     3    6    3
7   2     2    7    1
8   3     1    8    3
9   1     2    9    2
10  5     4   10    3
11  3     2   11    1
12  4     4   12    1
13  5     4   13    2
14  1     3   14    3
15  1     4   15    1
16  1     5   16    2
17  2     4   17    3
18  2     5   18    1
19  5     5   19    1


> dput(testData)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L), month = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
    yday = 1:19, week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", 
"month", "yday", "week"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

In the end, the output should look like this:

```
> output
  id month yday week
1  1     t    f    t
2  2     f    f    f
3  3     f    f    t
4  4     f    f    f
5  5     t    f    t
```

Comment: it's a new question, not a duplicate. please read it carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can group by `id` and then just check whether all elements of the range are in the values present for each group.  Note that `min(month)` gives the min for the grouped `id` variable, but `max(testData$month)` gives the max for the whole list.

```
library(dplyr)
tD2 <- testData %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(month=all(min(month):max(testData$month) %in% month),
            yday=all(min(yday):max(testData$yday) %in% yday),
            week=all(min(week):max(testData$week) %in% week))

tD2
# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id month  yday  week
  <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2     2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
3     3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4     4 FALSE FALSE FALSE
5     5  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```